# Extreme delay on startup when Eclipse RCP uses a target platform

Tags: eclipse-rcp, target-platform

I just upgraded my version of Eclipse to 4.5.1. I have a target platform and if I use it, it takes 1 min 45 seconds for the instance of Eclipse to startup. If I use the running platform instead, it takes all of 10 seconds.

I found this [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=446845)  which seems to suggest that the issue crept in between 4.5M1 and 4.5M2, but apparently has been fixed in the latest version of Mars. In light of my unsuccessful attempt, what specific version of Mars eliminates this issue if I use a target platform?

Comment: This works fine for me on 4.5.1

Comment: My target platform is composed of nothing but p2 update sites because we're leveraging tycho in our build process. Is that the same for you?

Comment: No, I am just using a couple of local directories.

Comment: So It appears the unresolved issue is with target platforms that use update sites. Is there any version of Mars that solved this issue?